# crawler break down, DUPEFILTER record 20000000+ uniqure url but jl record only 700000+ lines

Tags: scrapy, data-mining

I run a crawler with command "scrapy crawl any" in the dos window on my work computer with 16G ram and i5 12400 cpu.

Many times it broke down after the computer run slower and slower.

follwing is my code:

spider of any.py =================================================

```
class AnySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'any'
    allowed_domains = ['ali213.net', 'yxdown.com', 'gamersky.com', '3dmgame.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.ali213.net/','http://www.yxdown.com/', 'https://www.gamersky.com/', 'https://www.3dmgame.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        if isinstance(response, HtmlResponse):  # must be html

            pattern = re.compile(r'[\u4e00-\u9FFF]')  # must contain chinese charater
            result = pattern.findall(response.text)
            if len(result) < 20:
                return True

            item = YuceaiItem()
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['title'] = response.xpath("//title/text()").extract_first()
            item['html'] = response.text
            yield item

            for target_url in response.xpath("//a[not(contains(@rel, 'nofollow'))]/@href").extract():
                if target_url is not None and target_url != '' and 'search' not in target_url and '#' not in target_url and '?' not in target_url and 'javascript' not in target_url:
                    yield response.follow(target_url, callback=self.parse)
```

items.py ==============================================

```
class YuceaiItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    html = scrapy.Field()
```

middlewares.py ========================================

```
class CustomFilter(RFPDupeFilter):  # RFPDupeFilter  BaseDupeFilter
    """A dupe filter that considers specific ids in the url"""

    def __init__(self, dbconnection):
        super(CustomFilter, self).__init__()
        self.dbconnection = dbconnection

    def request_seen(self, request):
        
        if self.query_db(request.url) is not None:
            # print("=" * 100)
            # print("url: %s already exist" % request.url)
            return True
        else:
            self.insert_db(request.url)
            return False

    @classmethod
    def from_settings(cls, settings):
        dbargs = dict(
            host=settings.get("MYSQL_HOST", 'localhost'),
            db=settings.get("MYSQL_DB_NAME", 'scrapy_default'),
            user=settings.get("MYSQL_USER", 'root'),
            passwd=settings.get("MYSQL_PASSWORD", 'new.1234'),
            charset='utf8',
            use_unicode=True,
            port=settings.get("MYSQL_PORT", 3306)
        )

        dbconnection = pymysql.connect(**dbargs)
        return cls(dbconnection)

    def close(self, reason):
        self.dbconnection.close()

    def query_db(self, urlx):
        # sql = "select * from dupefilter where url='%s'"
        sql = "select * from dupefilter where url=%s"
        cursor = self.dbconnection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, (urlx,))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.close()
        return result

    def insert_db(self, urlx):
        timestamp = int(time.time())
        sql = "insert into dupefilter (url, addtime) values (%s, %s)"
        cursor = self.dbconnection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, (urlx, str(timestamp)))
        self.dbconnection.commit()
        cursor.close()
    # ... following are other generated code after command "scrapy startproject"
```

pipelines.py=============================================================

```
class YuceaiJlPipeline:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = None
        self.chunk_size = 5000  # set a paragraph num
        self.item_count = 0

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open('data.jl', 'a', encoding='utf-8')

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        if self.file:
            self.file.flush()
            self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # write items to json line file.
        line = json.dumps(dict(item), ensure_ascii=False) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)

        self.item_count += 1
        if self.item_count % self.chunk_size == 0:
            print("now total %d records in jl" % self.item_count)
            self.file.flush()

        return item
```

and I configurated the settings.py as following:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   # 'yuceai.pipelines.YuceaiMysqlPipeline': 300,
   'yuceai.pipelines.YuceaiJlPipeline': 1,
}

# ...

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'yuceai.middlewares.CustomFilter'
```

The above are the keypoint code snippet.

The mem used become higher and higher, I guess that's why my work computer broke down.
In fact, I move the dupefilter logic to mysql database for avoiding store the url in a set which will take more mem. as well, I customerize the YuceaiJlPipeline to flush the file by every 5000 for avoiding storing data in mem.

And when It broke down, I got 20000000+ records [unique urls] in the mysql database, but only got 700000+ lines in the data.jl file. these two number are so different!!! I don't know why. I think many many items missed in the process.

Where is the problem? what I really need is the data inside the json line file.
Besides, is there a way to keep my computer calms down against break down?

Comment: Can You please add to qestion stats of crawl job (ending log entry starting with "Dumping Scrapy stats:" ? Otherwise it is too much variants/reasons to cover in single answer

Comment: my work computer break down, I need to force restart my computer, I don't know where to get the dumping scrapy stats, I guess the mem exhausted. or cup 100%.

Comment: Rerun application with defined `MEMUSAGE_LIMIT_MB` setting. It's value must be high enough to reveal this issue and low enough to work without  https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.extensions.memusage . Also You may need to save logs to file as described here https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#logging-configuration

Comment: MEMUSAGE_LIMIT_MB, I look via the https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.extensions.memusage you mentiond above, it will close the spider when it reached the memory limited. It is not I want, I just want it fulfil the mission without break down.